# Exposing unexported filesystem mounted under ZFS volume as part of volumes NFS share

Tags: nfs, zfs, smartos, ufs

I have a ZFS Volume on my server I'm using as my network's NAS (called data/nas & part of the 'data' raidz zpool) and I am exposing this volume to my LAN via NFS using the ZFS attribute setting: sharenfs.  This works great and has been extremely simple to manage.

I recently got an 8TB Seagate Archival SMR HDD, full of some data I would like to expose via my NAS's NFS share.

As this is an archival SMR drive, I only want to mount and expose this drive in Read-Only mode (since rewrite performance on these drives is expectedly terrible) and it is probably not a good candidate to add to ZFS (both due to the fact that it has existing and that SMR drives are not the best performers under ZFS).  It's current format is UFS.

What I would like to do is mount the drive somewhere (say /mnt/foo) and then bind mount that location to a directory under my data/nas ZFS share, and thus expose the data through my existing NFS share.

I've read somewhere that setting some combination crossmnt and nohide in the sharenfs options could potentially allow this sort of relationship between two NFS exports.  However, since my archival drives are not ZFS, making it too an NFS export would not be quite as simple as is possible with a ZFS volume; even if this tactic were to work.

Does anyone know if this sort of cross filesystem NFS tactic could work, especially if the mounted child filesystem is not a ZFS NFS export (or any NFS export, for that matter)?  And if so, what kind of options would have to be configured to ensure reliable access to this sub-filesystem across the NAS connections?

FYI: this server is running SmartOS (Illumos) and thus has native ZFS and UFS filesystem support.